# Phonegap 2.2.0 iOS filetransfererror code 2

Tags: ios, xcode, html, cordova

```
saricsarda2[326:15b03] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
saricsarda2[326:15b03] -[CDVFileTransfer download:] [Line 313] File Transfer downloading file...
saricsarda2[326:15b03] File Transfer Finished with response code 200
saricsarda2[326:15b03] -[CDVFileTransferDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:] [Line 437] Write file file:///Users/Pannako/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/954E4293-9125-43B0-91F4-811C51291CCC/saricsarda2.app/www/data.json
saricsarda2[326:15b03] FileTransferError {
    code = 2;
    "http_status" = 200;
    source = "http://gastromania.hu/images/restaurants/214/mobile/data.json";
    target = "file:///Users/Pannako/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/954E4293-9125-43B0-91F4-811C51291CCC/saricsarda2.app/www/data.json";
}
saricsarda2[326:15b03] [LOG] Phonegap - download error source http://gastromania.hu/images/restaurants/214/mobile/data.json
saricsarda2[326:15b03] [LOG] Phonegap - download error target file:///Users/Pannako/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/954E4293-9125-43B0-91F4-811C51291CCC/saricsarda2.app/www/data.json
saricsarda2[326:15b03] [LOG] Phonegap - upload error code2
```

What's wrong whit this? I tried to find some information on the Internet, bit i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
target = "file:///Users/Pannako/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/954E4293-9125-43B0-91F4-811C51291CCC/saricsarda2.app/www/data.json";
```

you are trying to write inside the application folder and that is not allowed, instead you should save the info into de Documents folder, in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945375/phonegap-ios-how-to-get-app-documents-folder-full-path) you can see how to get a reference to it, and then change:

```
file:///Users/Pannako/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/954E4293-9125-43B0-91F4-811C51291CCC/saricsarda2.app
```

with the path to the Documents directory