# How to list files from iOS app document directory using cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

How can I see list of files stored in iOS app document directory using cordova?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the device's file system, you can use

**Cordova File Plugin**

[http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html](http://Cordova%20%20FILE%20Plugin)

Supports All Major Platforms iOS,Android, etc.

Comment: That I gone through, but I did not find how to get list of files from document directory. Do you have any sample code that could help me to get list of files from iOS document directory using cordova file plugin?

Comment: pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945375/phonegap-ios-how-to-get-app-documents-folder-full-path